# convert simple animation into a block based animation

Tags: iphone, animation

I have an animation that bounces a view slightly along the x axis. The problem is that is is using the old animation mechanism and as the documentation states use of block based animations are recommended for iOS4+. I'm wondering how I can turn this simple animation into a block based animation:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"bounce" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:2];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x + 10, self.view.center.y);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Also I want the view to return to its starting position after the animation ends, the method above bounces the view and increments its x value by 10 pixels.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Block-base animation's format is like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>
                      delay:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>
                    options:<#(UIViewAnimationOptions)#>
                 animations:<#^(void)animations#>
                 completion:<#^(BOOL finished)completion#>];
```

And the code below bounces the view `twice` and `go back to origin position`, **maybe there exists a better way**:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x + 10, self.view.center.y);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x - 10, self.view.center.y);
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f
                                           delay:0.0f
                                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                      animations:^{
                                          self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x + 10, self.view.center.y);
                                      }
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                          self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x - 10, self.view.center.y);
                                      }];
                 }];
```

And this one is similar, but `go back to origin position not smoothly`.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x + 10, self.view.center.y);
                     self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x - 10, self.view.center.y);
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

Comment: thanks @Kjuly the middle code block you supplied did the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:2];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 
                      delay:0.2 
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat) 
                 animations:^{
                     self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x + 10, self.view.center.y);
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

P.S. I haven't tried it...

Comment: thanks Ariel but this repeats the animation forever. I'm guessing I could put in some 'if' statement check but @Kjuly's answer lets me do with just animation blocks. gave you an up vote for your troubles anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

```
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse                 animations:^{
     self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x + 10, self.view.center.y);
     } completion:nil];
```

This should do it, but I don't think there is a way to specify the autorepeat count.